# Why does this simple nodejs programm with promises run forever?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am running a rather simple nodejs program, which fetches some rows from a mssql database, does something with them, and then should exit.

Instead, it does what it is supposed to do, but then keeps running forever.

Did I forget anything to allow the program to finish?

Or is it simply that my expectation that the program will exit when all promises have been fulfilled is wrong, and I need to terminate it manually?

```
'use strict';
var mssql = require('mssql');

var myssqlConfig = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: '...',
    port: 1435,
    database: '...'
};

mssql.connect(myssqlConfig).then(function() {

    new mssql.Request()
    .input('someRow', mssql.VarChar(), 'someValue')
    .query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE someColumn > @someValue")
    .then(function(recordset){
            // do non-relevant stuff with the record set.
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('Error: '+err);
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
     console.log('Connection Error: '+err);
});
```

Comment: `mssql.connect` sets up a persistent connection, which is keeping your process alive.  If you disconnect from mssql your process will exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the process to exit, you have to call `process.exit()`. You can send it a exit state of 0 or 1 to indicate if it's clean or an error state.  That will cause it to exit immediately.

If you want it to exit after finishing its current work (i.e. pending async tasks) you'd set `process.exitCode = 0` or 1 if it's in error,  that's a more graceful exit.

For the latter to work, you'll actually need to disconnect from the DB as well, since the open connection will be treated as pending work.

Comment: Closing the connection was indeed what I was missing.